# How to remove unused div in wordpress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make Wordpress loop with php modulus. The scenario is wrapping every 3 posts in a `div`. My script below is working perfectly, except I found an unused empty `div` at the last (from inspect element).

```
$loop_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $loop_args );

<?php if( $loop->have_posts() ): ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $count++; ?>
        <?php if( $count % 3 == 0 ): ?>
        <article class="post-content"><?php the_title();?></article>
    </div> <!-- .col md 6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php else: ?>
        <article class="post-content"><?php the_title();?></article>
        <?php endif; // end modulus ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end while loop ?>
    </div> <!-- .col md 6 -->
</div> <!-- .row -->

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Please take a look at the last highlighted `div` in my attachement:

[screenshot preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQKvO.png)

How can I remove that unused empty `div`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $count++; ?>
            <?php if( $count % 3 == 1 && $count > 1 ): ?>
                </div> <!-- .col md 6 -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <article class="post-content"><?php the_title();?></article>
            <?php else: ?>
                <article class="post-content"><?php the_title();?></article>
            <?php endif; // end modulus ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end while loop ?>
    </div> <!-- .col md 6 -->
</div> <!-- .row -->
```

Here I don't close `div` on the third `article` but I open it if I need on the fourth.

Comment: Thanks @Jouby. I've never think that was so simple. Now it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you are allways opeining the `<div class="col-md-6">` when the modulus 3 is 0 even if there are no more articles after you open the tag. In such case you would end up  with an empty div.